# Transforming a Bézier Curve by a Complex Function

Tags: splines, coordinate-transformation

I have a method to plot a rectangular region and then plot the lattice transformation by some complex function $f[z]$.

```
latticeTransform[f_: Function, xrange_: Range, yrange_: Range] :=
  (curve = Graphics[BezierCurve[RandomPoint[
       Rectangle[{xrange[[2]], yrange[[2]]}, {xrange[[3]],yrange[[3]]}], 6]]];
   dom = Show[{ParametricPlot[{x, y}, xrange, yrange, 
       AspectRatio -> 1], curve}]; 
   image = ParametricPlot[{Re[f[z]], Im[f[z]]} /. z -> x + I*y, xrange, 
     yrange, PlotRange -> All];
   GraphicsGrid[{{dom, image}}, ImageSize -> Large]);
```

I added the Bézier curve to visualize how a random curve will get transformed in the output, but I'm not entirely sure how to map it onto the image. I thought about storing the random points I generated, transforming them with $f[z]$, and then calling `BezierCurve[]` on the points again, but I believe this wouldn't be a true mapping as Bézier will recalculate and find a new curve.

Is this correct? If so, how would I draw the curve transformed by $f[z]$?

**Edit:** My only other thought is to get a list of points `{x, y}` on the Bézier curve and generate a new list by `f[x + I y]`, but again I'm unsure of how to do this and it has a tradeoff of accuracy vs. computation time.

Comment: A Bézier curve after an arbitrary complex transformation will of course not necessarily be a Bézier curve anymore.

Comment: Counter example : A exact circle can't be represented with a Bezier curve, though it is the transformation of a straight line by a complex function.

Comment: @J.M. thanks, so I can't just call Bezier curve again. But how would I transform the curve by the function? I'm more interested in mapping the curve than the semantics of a Bezier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to work a bit harder to demonstrate the complex transformation of a Bézier curve; in particular, you need to express the curve explicitly in terms of the Bernstein basis before transforming. Here's an example:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom["bezier"]; (* for reproducibility *)
 With[{f = Function[x, ArcTan[x]], xrange = {-5, 5}, yrange = {-4, 4}},

      (* generate random Bézier curve explicitly *)
      pts = RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {xrange, yrange}] @ RandomReal[1, {6, 2}];
      n = Length[pts] - 1;
      {bf[t_], bg[t_]} = BernsteinBasis[n, Range[0, n], t].pts;

      GraphicsRow[{Show[ParametricPlot[{x, y}, Prepend[xrange, x] // Evaluate, 
                                       Prepend[yrange, y] // Evaluate,
                                       AspectRatio -> Automatic, Mesh -> True,
                                       PlotStyle -> None], 
                        ParametricPlot[{bf[t], bg[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]], 
                   Show[ParametricPlot[ReIm[f[x + I y]], Prepend[xrange, x] // Evaluate,
                                       Prepend[yrange, y] // Evaluate, 
                                       AspectRatio -> Automatic, Mesh -> True,
                                       PlotStyle -> None], 
                        ParametricPlot[ReIm[f[bf[t] + I bg[t]]], {t, 0, 1}]]}]]]
```

[image: mesh and Bézier curve, pre- and post-transformation]

Turning the entire business into a suitable `Manipulate[]` is left as an exercise for the interested reader.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to read up on the Bernstein basis. Would you happen to have a recommendation on a cleaner way to generate a random curve and transform it? maybe without Béziers?

Comment: Your "and transform it" is the source of the complication in this case. Some math to ponder: Bézier curves (and more generally B-spline curves) only remain as such under an *affine* transformation, and such transformations can be done easily by transforming only the control points instead of the entire curve.